# How can I queue all messages on Java ThreadPoolExecutor and check that each message is processed?

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, amqp

Im processing queued messages using Java ThreadPoolExecutor with a fixed pool size of 10. When the number of threads reaches maximum, I seem to be losing some messages in the process. How does ThreadPoolExecutor ensure that all messages in the queue are processed?

This is for a Rabbitmq SDK client, I receive messages and push them to the ThreadPoolExecutor so that they do not block the main thread. I have tried setting the pool size to 1 so that messages are processed 1 at a time, but still I am missing some updates.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
       OddsChanged task = new OddsChanged(oddsChanges);
        System.out.println("New Task Created and added to Threadpool");
        executor.execute(task);
```

Once the pool size hits the maximum of 10, it seems to skip the logic inside the thread. Only printing "New Task Created and added to Threadpool" and ignores the code inside the task. When increase the pool size I get database deadlock errors on the Aurora-MYSQL database.

How can I ensure all messages are processed? Is there a better approach to this kind of processing.

Comment: The message can not be missed. You can put a log message in the run method of the task. If you still facing issue can you please paste your run method implemtation.

Comment: If you use a `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);` implementation of `ThreadPoolExecutor` you shouldn't be losing the submitted tasks even when the you exceed the number of threads in the pool, this because internally it uses a `LinkedBlockingQueue` with an unbounded capacity.

Comment: Are you using a `RejectedExecutionHandler.AbortPolicy` ?